# Service Worker Making Duplicate Fetch Request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

Iv been wrestling with this for hours now and i'm sure the answer is something simple im missing.  Iv only been working with Service Workers for a little while and could use some help here.

Basically im creating a simple service worker that will cache assets, but also HTML responses. Pretty standard.

The strategy im using is to retrieve the items from the cache, but also perform a fetch at the same time to update the cache.  So you get the benefit of cache speed and offline ability, but also refreshing the cache each time to keep things up to date.

It's all working fine, except for the HTML page, which is authenticated via an `Authorization token <token>`  style header

The initial request, works fine, the request is of type `navigate`, the header is passed through and the page loads as expected (verified by logging out the header in the service worker, and also viewing my API logs), however there is a follow up request coming from somewhere, that is of type `no-cors` which contains no headers, and triggers a redirect and breaks the caching.

In my code sample here, I can clearly see the Authorization header is logged out in the first request, so it is there at some point,  but in the second follow up request its blank.

Im not sure why that is, or how to fix it.  The only thing iv been able to do to make it work, was to hardcode the header and token into the `fetch` to test it works.  This is obviously not a solution though.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?  or why there is even a follow up second `no-cors` request being made?

Code

```
var cacheName = "v1-" + date.getMonth();
var cacheAssets = ["/app/index.html"];

self.addEventListener("install", function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(cacheAssets).then(() => self.skipWaiting());
        })
    );
});

// If there's a cached version available, use it, but also fetch an update for next time.
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    let request = event.request;
    const authToken = request.headers.get("Authorization");
    console.log("AUTH HEADER", authToken, request.url);

    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
                var fetchPromise = fetch(request).then(function(networkResponse) {
                    console.log(
            "Storing Fresh Copy:",
            event.request.url,
            networkResponse.clone()
          );
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
                    return networkResponse;
                });
                return response || fetchPromise;
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using Workbox? Or is there a reason you aren’t?

Comment: Well, its such a small amount of code. It seems excessive to implement a whole framework when I can get it done with this minimal 40 lines of code.  Is there any particular reason I would need to?

Comment: It really helps with some of this type of gotcha, and you can import only the parts you need.

Comment: Also I think you have a race condition in your returns, but its hard to tell in this context. do you have this in a codesandbox or something?

Comment: Hmm ok.. maybe i'll try Workbox,  im currently just dealing with the excess 401's with a fail-fast approach.  its working other than that, but it doesnt feel right.     I dont have it in a code sandbox, im not entirely sure how to put a service working into a sandbox